# Stub class instance inside module that doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

For a spec, I am trying to stub a new class (MyClass) inside a new module (NewModule) both of which do not exist yet.

This spec is for the class which utilizes MyClass

```rb
let(:my_class) { instance_double('ParentModule::NewModule::MyClass', extract_values: expected_value) }
```

ParentModule: already exist

NewModule: Doesn't yet exist

MyClass: Doesn't yet exist

Unfortunately, it throws this error

```
NameError:
       uninitialized constant ParentModule::NewModule
```

Any suggestions what would be the correct way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub a constant via [`stub_const`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/mutating-constants/stub-undefined-constant):

```
let(:my_class) { stub_const('ParentModule::NewModule::MyClass', Class.new) }
```

From the docs:

> When the constant is not already defined, all the
>   necessary intermediary modules will be dynamically created. When the example completes,
>   the intermediary module constants will be removed to return the constant state to how it
>   started.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stefan's suggestion above, this is what worked for me.

```
# Modules Abc and Pqr also do not exist yet
let(:class_name) { 'Abc::Pqr::SomeMagic' }
let(:fake_class) { Class.new { def do_some_magic; end } }
let(:magic_class) { class_double(stub_const(class_name, fake_class)).as_stubbed_const }
let(:magic_class_instance) { instance_double(magic_class) }

before do
  allow(magic_class).to(receive(:new).and_return(magic_class_instance))
  allow(magic_class_instance).to(receive(:do_some_magic).and_return('some value'))
end
```